# How to update to the new version of React-Native on the current (WIP) project

Tags: react-native, dependencies, upgrade, updates

What is the best way how can I update (WIP) React Native project to the newer version?

I tried to update my project but from that moment the project won't work. And the only solution was to go back to the previous version.

I found this manual solution (https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.61.5&to=0.63.2), but I hope that there is some automated solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic solution. Update your libraries manually. Use this tool to view changes in react-native versions.

> https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

Comment: Ok, thanks, I understand that is the only the hard way.

Comment: Mark my text as an answer if it helped you

Answer (score -1):

Each version is different. Upgrading has always been sort of a pain point. The best solution is applying the changes shown in [ReactNative Upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) and then debugging the issues one by one or checking online for a matching version bump. in our case from 0.60 to 62.2 we had change and rebuild some swift files within XCode which we found out about using react native upgrade helper. What's not working right now?